# Symfony 2 error class not found in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

Tags: php, symfony

I would like add form services with security context as bellow:

```
namespace Infogold\AccountBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class KonsultantType extends AbstractType {

     protected $user;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $user) {


        $this->user = $user;
    }
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
  public function getName() {
        return 'konsultanci_form';
    }
```

In services :

```
parameters:
#    infogold_account.example.class: Infogold\AccountBundle\Example

services:

   form.type.konsultanci_form:
       class:  Infogold\AccountBundle\Form\KonsulantType
       arguments: ['@security.context'] 
       tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: konsultanci_form }
```

And I get this error:

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Infogold\AccountBundle\Form\KonsulantType' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony4\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 718

718 line is:

```
protected function getForm_Type_KonsultanciFormService()
    {
        return $this->services['form.type.konsultanci_form'] = new \Infogold\AccountBundle\Form\KonsulantType($this->get('security.context'));
    }
```

Where I made a mistake ?

Comment: You created a class which name is `KonsultantType`. And in your service.yml, you put the class as `Infogold\AccountBundle\Form\KonsulantType`. It is a little mistake on class name.

Comment: It's normal to specify namespace in service configration, do you have refreshed the cache ? with cache:clear command ? oh sorry @marcoshoya i did'nt saw the mistake on classname

Comment: @JonaPkr In the class the name is KonsulTANTtype. On service file, the name is KonsuLANTtype. See again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said, it is a mistake on class name. It is `KonsultantType` instead of `KonsulantType`

Try:

```
parameters:
#    infogold_account.example.class: Infogold\AccountBundle\Example

services:

   form.type.konsultanci_form:
       class:  Infogold\AccountBundle\Form\KonsultantType
       arguments: ['@security.context'] 
       tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: konsultanci_form }
```

Comment: yeah didn't saw the mistype, i thought you were talking about the fact that the namespace was specified. upvote for u :)